# How to dynamically display a placeholder and deselect the other options, in a select form menu using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have the following drop-down menu:

```
<form action="...">
    <select name="fruits" id="my-fruits">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a fruit</option>
        <option value="apple">apple</option>
        <option value="orange">orange</option>
        <option value="peach">peach</option>
    </select>
    <select name="animals" id="my-animals">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select an animal</option>
        <option value="dog">dog</option>
        <option value="cat">cat</option>
        <option value="iguana">iguana</option>
        ></select>
</form>
```

What I need is when the user changes the selected option in one  filed (*i.e. on change event*), the placeholder to be displayed on the other and vice-versa.

For example, lets say that the user had already selected `orange` in  `#my-fruits`. Now, **when the user changes the selection** from `dog` to `cat` in `#my-animals`:

1. the placeholder `"Select a fruit"` to be displayed automatically on `#my-fruits` field, and
2. then, the `<option value="orange">` have its "`selected`" attribute removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ira, try this:

```
$('#my-fruits')
  .add('#my-animals')
  .on('change', function () {
    $(this).siblings().prop('selectedIndex', 0);
  });
```

Also, remove unnecessary arrow in this line:

`></select>`

Good luck ;)

Comment: .siblings() and prop('selectedIndex', 0) did the trick, thanks @Anton Goncharuk

Comment: @ira you are welcome. Hope you enjoy your further learning JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  $(this).siblings('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
  console.log($('option:selected', this).val())
  console.log($(this).siblings('select').val())

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="...">
  <select name="fruits" id="my-fruits">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select a fruit</option>
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="orange">orange</option>
    <option value="peach">peach</option>
  </select>
  <select name="animals" id="my-animals">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select an animal</option>
    <option value="dog">dog</option>
    <option value="cat">cat</option>
    <option value="iguana">iguana</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

1. Just set the selected option of sibling select to first index

Comment: thank you, it actually works pretty well, I'm now working on subsequently removing the "selected" attribute

Comment: @ira glad it helps

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$('#animals').change(function() {
    $('#fruits').val("");
});
```

Comment: this does not give a helpful answer